# Form validation in Symfony2 wont go away

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I made this Controller to play around with Symfony 2.3

```
namespace AskThem\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AskThem\MainBundle\Entity\Task;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    private $context = array();

    public function indexAction(Request $request) {

        $task = new Task();

        $form =
            $this->createFormBuilder($task)
                ->add("task", "text")
                ->add("dueDate", "date")
                ->add("save", "submit")
                ->add("saveAndAdd", "submit")
                ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // ... perform some action, such as saving the task to the database

            $nextAction = $form->get('saveAndAdd')->isClicked()
                ? 'homepage'
                : 'task_success';

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($nextAction));
        }

        $this->context["form"] = $form->createView();
        return $this->render('AskThemMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig', $this->context);
    }

    public function successAction(Request $request) {
        return new Response("Victory");
    }
}
```

The form was working fine, so then I added a `validation-yml` file with some `NotBlank` rules to test if it would work, and indeed it did.

But when I deleted those rules (I even deleted the whole file) the form still kept presenting itself with the `required` attribute. How do I turn off the validation?

Comment: `'require' => false` in the form builder options

Comment: How do I set up the Form Builder Options? Could you please post in the answer area?

Comment: ->add("task", "text", array('required' => false))  required is set true by default, this has nothing to do with validation.yml, it's the browser that is doing this, you just didn't notice before.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#required